# No module named pip on Travis CI

Tags: python, python-3.x, travis-ci

I have a multi-language build for my project that uses Java (8) and Python (2.7, 3.6). I'm trying to setup a continuous integration system using Travis CI but I'm having trouble running pip on my build script as Travis CI keeps telling me:

```
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip
```

I've tried this with a very simple build script:

```
python3 -m pip --version
```

I've also tried calling pip in Python 3 directly as `pip3` but I got another error saying something like module pip is availale in the following Python installation (with a list of versions 3.6, and 3.6.3).

I have the following matrix to setup my build environment:

```
matrix:
    include:
        - language: java
          jdk: openjdk8
        - language: python
          python:
              - 2.7
              - 3.6
```

I was expecting specifying Python 3.6 in here will setup pip as well as it's been how things are since 3.4 if I understand correctly. Anything else I'm missing?

---

Update:

Based on the earlier responses I got, I added the following to the `before_script` script:

```
before_script:
    - python2.7 -m pip || wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python2.7
    - python3 -m pip || wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
```

But I'm still getting the same error:

```
$ python2.7 -m pip || wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python2.7 
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

$ python3 -m pip || wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3 
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip
--2018-01-03 11:52:33--  https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
Resolving bootstrap.pypa.io (bootstrap.pypa.io)... 151.101.0.175,
151.101.64.175, 151.101.128.175, ... 
Connecting to bootstrap.pypa.io (bootstrap.pypa.io)|151.101.0.175|:443... connected. 
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK 
Length: 1595408 (1.5M) [text/x-python] Saving to: ‘get-pip.py’ 

100%[======================================>] 1,595,408   --.-K/s   in 0.1s     

2018-01-03 11:52:34 (13.5 MB/s) - ‘get-pip.py’ saved [1595408/1595408]

$ python3 -m pip --version /usr/bin/python3: No module named pip
```

Comment: a plain python doesn't contain pip.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pip, try something like this

```
wget -qO- https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Travis will run *two* builds, first with python 2.7 then with 3.6, rather than installing everything into the same VM. The 2.7 one will lack pip. Furthermore, even if it did install everything into same VM, you should still run pip with the right python version to avoid problems.

You can also install it only when needed with something like

```
script:
    python -m pip || wget -qO- https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Comment: Does this mean it won't be possible to have an all-in-one environment that should be able to run my build script then? My build script requires that the build environment has all Java and Python versions installed simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, that is possible if you use "include" like you have done. Updating question

Comment: The problem is you want to run two builds, one for 2.7 and one for 3.6, if you stick to 3.6, you should be fine.

Comment: So there's one part of my project that runs on Python 2.7. Won't setting up only Python 3 cause issues?

Comment: Even after adding the script, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: oh, it was bad usage of wget, you need the `-qO-` flag to pipe to stdout.

Comment: Try with the updated version, you can also use curl.